# Advice on pursuing higher education after working for 7 years

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, united-states, recommendation-letter, university

I completed bachelors in Mechanical engineering in 2013 and have been working since Jan 2014. My current job as a 'manufacturing engineer' is a non-technical back office job (because I'm from India where my bachelors does not really mean what it's titled) where many MNCs set-up their back offices.

I just wanted to start earning when I finished studying and hence did not bother much about higher education. Now, after working for 7 years, I've started to think about pursuing higher education in the field of engineering, with my specific interest being Robotics.

I do not have any experience pertaining to the field of Robotics. But I've started studying math diligently in-order to prepare myself for the knowledge that I'm aiming to acquire to be able to get myself into that field.

I want to study MS Robotics from a good university (and do a PhD after that), possibly a US based one. To do that, I'd require letters of recommendation from either my professors or someone of repute whom I work with in that field (Robotics in my case). It's been 7 years since I've finished my bachelors and since I'm working an a field that has nothing to do with Robotics, the chances of me getting a LoR form someone relevant is non-existent.

I do not know how to pursue my target of getting into a decent university for Robotics (but I'm doing self study regardless). It would be of great help if someone can give me some practical piece of advice on how I may go further in that path.

Comment: Are you within easy travel distance of a good university? I suspect so, from your profile.

Comment: @Buffy In the USA? No. I'm from India.

Comment: Yes, I meant Karnataka.

Comment: @Buffy Yes. There's the Indian Institute of Science in Bangalore which is a premier institute in India.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me suggest that you make an appointment to visit the head of department at some "interesting" department at the university. Ask for a meeting to discuss your future briefly.

In the meeting ask to be put in touch with a professor or two, preferably in robotics, preferably educated outside India, so that they have some foreign experience.

Then work with them on a plan to get you started. It may be that the institute itself is your best option. But they might have some suggestions about things you can do to build a portfolio, leading to your goals. You might even have skills that could benefit a professor there as a way to get started.

But if you can build a portfolio that would get you admitted to a good Indian institute, it would probably also work in US. People there can advise you on that.

Note, however, that if you want to study for a masters in US that they are almost always unfunded. And living here, in some places, is very expensive. Doctorates, on the other hand, are usually funded through appointment as a TA (or RA).

---

Sorry if this has a bit of US bias where professors and department heads would be likely to talk to you - briefly. I suspect that India is also a bit "informal" about such things, but don't know that. Personality matters in such things, of course, and some will be more helpful than others.

Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Let me do that.

Comment: Definitely worth a try, but it is very less likely that anyone will probably give you time. Most professors in India are not so tolerant, as far as my knowledge goes. It will be better if, in your first email, you simply ask for advice in the email itself rather than requesting an appointment. Most of the time, you won't even get a reply to the email. Also mention why you specifically seek that person's advice and why that is important to you.